# multiple cURL downloading with 404 detection

Tags: bash, shell, curl, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to write a shell script that downloads files using cURL and detects if a url leads to a 404 error. If a url is a 404 then I want to save the url link or filename to a text file.

The url format is http://server.com/somefile[00-31].txt

I've been messing around with what I've found on google and currently have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if curl --fail -O "http://server.com/somefile[00-31].mp4"
then
  echo "$var" >> "files.txt"    
else
  echo "Saved!"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

URLFORMAT="http://server.com/somefile%02d.txt"

for num in {0..31}; do
    # build url and try to download
    url=$(printf "$URLFORMAT" $num)
    CURL=$(curl --fail -O "$url" 2>&1)

    # check if error and 404, and save in file
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $CURL | grep --quiet 'The requested URL returned error: 404'
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "$url" >> "files.txt"
    fi

done
```

Here is a version which uses the arguments for URLs:

```
#!/bin/sh

for url in "$@"; do
    CURL=$(curl --fail -O "$url" 2>&1)
    # check if error and 404, and save in file
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $CURL | grep --quiet 'The requested URL returned error: 404'
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "$url" >> "files.txt"
    fi
done
```

You can use this like: sh download-script.sh http://server.com/files{00..21}.png http://server.com/otherfiles{00..12}.gif

The range expansion will work on bash shells.

Comment: thank you for your response. but the main reason i want to have this script is so i can run a command like `sh downloadscript.sh http://server.com/files[00-21].png http://server.com/otherfiles[00-12].gif`

Comment: @natehome added a second script which will use the arguments for url processing.

Comment: so it works!... but the script doesn't make the url with 2 digits (sorry thats really awkwardly phrased). i need it so that the urls are  ...pic00.png, ...pic01.png. also for the urls that are not 404's it doesnt show the download progress. sorry for all the noobish questions and stuff. ive only really worked with bash and sh for the first time today

Comment: @natehome it may work only with latest bash version, you can also use: `sh downloadscript.sh http://server.com/files0{0..9}.png http://server.com/files{10..21}.png http://server.com/otherfiles0{0..9}.gif http://server.com/otherfiles{10..12}.gif` as workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-D, --dump-header <file>` option to capture all headers, including Content-Type and HTTP Status Code. Note that the headers may be terminated with a DOS newline (CR LF), so you may want to strip the CR character.

```
curl -s -D headers.txt -o out.dat "http://server.com/somefile[00-31].mp4"
httpStatus=$(head -1 headers.txt | awk '{print $2}')
contentType=$(grep "Content-Type:" headers.txt | tr -d '\r')
contentType=${contentType#*: }
if [ "$httpStatus" != "200" ]; then
    echo "FAILED - HTTP STATUS $httpStatus"
else
    echo "SAVED"
fi
```